# Cannot mount a RAID1 array

Tags: mount, raid

I installed Ubuntu server 16 (Linux version 4.4.0-38-generic (buildd@lgw01-58) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) )) and chose to set up a RAID1 at installation using three disks (the boot separate on a fourth) to use them as data storage.

It seems that the RAID is ok but will not mount. I don't understand if it is a filesystem problem. At installation there was no option for filesystem and it is listed under fdisk as "HPFS/NTFS/exFAT". Specifying any of those gives an error at mount (trying to mount at '/scratch'):

```
mount /dev/md0 /scratch
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/md0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/md0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Various test outputs are below. Thanks for any help. S.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[1] sdb1[0] sdd1[2]
      1953381376 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=10-115-66-42:0 UUID=a44eb3e4:20bee35e:2c6c6819:e4a4ed83

dmsetup ls
10--115--66--42--vg-root        (252:0)
10--115--66--42--vg-swap_1      (252:1)

dmsetup table
10--115--66--42--vg-root: 0 1902182400 linear 8:5 2048
10--115--66--42--vg-swap_1: 0 50331648 linear 8:5 1902184448

file -s -L /dev/mapper/*
/dev/mapper/10--115--66--42--vg-root:   Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=750c998b-8c36-4f5f-84de-cbe07fb4794c (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
/dev/mapper/10--115--66--42--vg-swap_1: Linux/i386 swap file (new style), version 1 (4K pages), size 6291455 pages, no label, UUID=8ed911a4-0069-493a-bc02-8945b41fbc18
/dev/mapper/control:                    ERROR: cannot read `/dev/mapper/control' (Invalid argument)

fdisk -l /dev/sd*
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6ab41cea

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048     999423     997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 1953523711 1952522242  931G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 1953523711 1952522240  931G 8e Linux LVM
Disk /dev/sda1: 487 MiB, 510656512 bytes, 997376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda2: 1 KiB, 1024 bytes, 2 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00016824

Device      Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda2p1          2 1952522241 1952522240  931G 8e Linux LVM
Disk /dev/sda5: 931 GiB, 999691386880 bytes, 1952522240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x57d341ca

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk /dev/sdb1: 1.8 TiB, 2000396746752 bytes, 3907024896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1p1      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdb1p2      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdb1p3      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdb1p4      4294967295 5035196669  740229375  353G ff BBT
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x57d341cc

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk /dev/sdc1: 1.8 TiB, 2000396746752 bytes, 3907024896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1p1      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdc1p2      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdc1p3      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdc1p4      4294967295 5035196669  740229375  353G ff BBT
Disk /dev/sdd: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x57d341cd

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk /dev/sdd1: 1.8 TiB, 2000396746752 bytes, 3907024896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1p1      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdd1p2      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdd1p3      4294967295 8589934589 4294967295    2T ff BBT
/dev/sdd1p4      4294967295 5035196669  740229375  353G ff BBT
root@10-115-66-42:/home/theoa# mount -t hpfs /dev/md0 /scratch
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```